# Is there a search algorithm that keeps searching an ordered list until all values are equal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, search

I have an object in JavaScript with four keys. Each key stores an array with values. It looks like this:

```
{
  one: [...],
  two: [...],
  three: [...],
  four: [...]
}
```

Let's say each element in the array is an object of class 'Test' that has a boolean key called 'complete'.

If I choose to start from array three, I need to find the first occurrence of `Test.complete` equals `true`. If that occurrence is found in array three, let's say I return that value / some other value from that object. If that occurrence is not in array three, I then need to loop through four, one and two (in that order). If I start from two, then loop through two, three, four, and one (in that order).

Assuming there is a button on the page that toggles this `complete` value to `true`, at some point there are going to be no more `false` values left, and that is the point where I want to stop looping through these Test object arrays.

I know I can use `Object.keys(obj)` to access the keys, and maybe have a function that returns the order `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']` I need to loop through depending on what the starting array is.

Is if there is an existing search algorithm that I could use directly or easily modify for this use case? I have an implementation that uses recursion, but it does not loop all the way around and keep looping until all `Test.complete` values are `true`.

Comment: First problem is that you're expecting order from an object, which offers no such guarantees of ordering. You'll need to make sure that you have some way to statically define the order.

Comment: I am aware of this. That's what I meant by - "have a function that returns the order `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']`". This function will basically be a switch-case that returns the order depending on the starting key of the object.

Comment: If you have that array with the keys in the correct order then you can loop through the arrays from any starting position with for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) obj[keys[(startIndex + i) % keys.length]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first. You cannot let your loop block execution until the data structure looks like you want it to. A single function invocation will always see same object no matter how many times you loop. What you need to do is wait for the next tick and then invoke the function again, for example using `setTimeout`. This also means that to wait for your function to finish you need to use callbacks or promises, not `return`.

This is not going to work:

```
function waitLoop(obj) {
   while (notDone) {
      ...
   }
   return;
}
waitLoop(myObj); // Blocks until done
```

Instead you need to approach something like this:

```
var obj = ...;
function waitLoop(callback) { // Note that callback is a function!
   ...
   if (notDone) {
       setTimeout(function () {
           waitLoop(callback);
       }, 0); // setTimeout(..., 0) waits until the next tick
   } else {
       callback();
   }
}

waitLoop(function () {
    // Do something here when waitLoop is done
});
```

This is the very basics of asynchronous execution in Javascript. You can also read up on promises, which is a similar concept but with a slightly different interface.

On to your problem. It looks like you want to keep returning the first found value and then continue looping. This means you need to have a callback that can be invoked on every iteration and either return a value or return that it is done looping. You should do something like this:

```
var obj = ...;
function waitUntilComplete(callback) {
    let keyOrder = ['three', 'four', 'one', 'two'];
    for (let k = 0; k < keyOrder.length; k++) {
        let a = obj[keyOrder[k]];
        for (let k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
            let testResult = Test.complete(a[k]));
            if (testResult) {
                // Send back the value and end execution
                callback(false, a[k]);
                setTimeout(function (){
                    waitUntilComplete(callback);
                }, 0);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Complete!
    callback(true, null);
}

waitUntilComplete(function (done, returnValue) {
    if (!done) {
        // Do what you want with returnValue
    } else {
        // Done, Test.complete returns false for all values!
    }
});
```

One thing remains to be explained: The `tick`. But let us go back to basics. Javascript is single-threaded, with an event queue. The queue starts empty. Sometimes events happen: you click a button that have an event handler, setTimeout fires or your document completes loading. In these cases an event is pushed onto the event queue. You can look at an "event" as a function. After all, you register event handlers as functions. The function is pushed onto the queue. Then what? Nothing. It just sits there in the queue. From time to time the runtime wakes up and starts to loop through the event queue, invoking all the functions in order. This is what we call a `tick`.

This should help you understand why you can not have a function that blocks while waiting for some external event. Because all events - button clicks, timeouts etc - are just pushed onto the queue. But the runtime will not invoke the next function on the queue until the current function have returned! A blocking function would block everything else from happening.

That is why we use callbacks and why I use `setTimeout` to schedule the next loop. `waitUntilComplete` above will loop through all arrays once, then it will *schedule a new invocation in the next tick*. This lets all other queued events happen so that there is a chance for `obj` to be updated between the loops.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and solution! I am familiar with callbacks and promises, but it did not occur to me that I could use it in this situation.